# InStr not finding the substring

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vast group of text formulas in one worksheet column that i need to convert to a proper excel formula (e.g. `(dAA11b+dAA12b)/dAA13b*100`). For that I'm creating a macro in vba so I can convert them all automatically.

I defined two strings that will be inserted before the letter "d" and right before the next operator (e.g. "+"). For the first code (`dAA11b`) I was able to add the desired strings in the correct places but when the next time the InStr function finds the next "d" it isn't able to the same job (it should detect ")" or "/" which are the next operators (defined ")" as one aswell) but instead it's only able to detect "*".

I'm able to get

`=(VLOOKUP("dAA11b";Variáveis;MATCH(F1;Variáveis!$A$1:$AD$1;0);FALSE)+`

but the desired result is

`=(VLOOKUP("dAA11b";Variáveis;MATCH(F1;Variáveis!$A$1:$AD$1;0);FALSE)+VLOOKUP("dAA12b";Variáveis;MATCH(F1;Variáveis!$A$1:$AD$1;0);FALSE))/VLOOKUP("dAA13ab";Variáveis;MATCH(F1;Variáveis!$A$1:$AD$1;0);FALSE)*100`

```
Sub calc()

str_var = "VLOOKUP("""
str_var1 = """;Variáveis;MATCH(F1;Variáveis!$A$1:$AD$1;0);FALSE)"

cel = Worksheets(2).Cells(2, 3) '(dAA11b+dAA12b)/dAA13b*100
str_f = ""

With Sheets("Indicadores")

i = 1
Do While Not terminou
carater = Mid(cel, i, 1)
    If carater = "d" Then
    str_f = str_f & str_var
    b = InStr(i, Mid(cel, i, 999), ")", vbTextCompare)
    c = InStr(i, Mid(cel, i, 999), "+", vbTextCompare)
    d = InStr(i, Mid(cel, i, 999), "-", vbTextCompare)
    e = InStr(i, Mid(cel, i, 999), "*", vbTextCompare)
    f = InStr(i, Mid(cel, i, 999), "/", vbTextCompare)

    minimo = 0
    If b <> 0 Then
    minimo = b
    End If

    If c <> 0 And c < minimo Then
    minimo = c
    End If

    If d <> 0 And d < minimo Then
    minimo = d
    End If

    If e <> 0 And e < minimo Then
    minimo = e
    End If

    If f <> 0 And f < minimo Then
    minimo = f
    End If

    a = Mid(cel, i, minimo - 1)

    str_f = str_f & a & str_var1
    .Cells(567, 3).Value = str_f

    'i = i + 6

    End If


carater = Mid(cel, i, 1)
    If carater = "+" Then

    str_f = str_f & "+"
    .Cells(567, 3).Value = str_f

    End If


i = i + 1

Loop
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question, but you may want to use `Split()` and make the deliminator `"d"`. Then write a `For Each` looping through the resulting array rather than looping through every character like you do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind i found the solution. After looping every intended character the `InStr(i, Mid(cel, i, 999)` assumes the mid function without the first part of the formula (`dAA11b+`) and defines the next "d" as the first position (i=1), so when it was searching for the next character (i=9) it was already looking in the 3rd "d" and obviously ignored the ")" and "/" operators since they were behind the new i=1. The solution was to replace "i" for "1" in `InStr(1, Mid(cel, i, 999)`